# Mean and Variance Temperature Conversion

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation

In June, New York City's daily maximum temperature has a mean of 80 °F and standard deviation of 5°F. What is the absolute difference in mean and variance in °C?

I don't know what possible mistake I could be making in the following approach:

$$°F = \frac95 °C + 32 $$
$=> SD(°F) = \frac95 SD(°C)$
$=> Var(°F) = \frac{81}{25}Var(°C)$

$=> Mean(°F) = \frac95 Mean(°C) + 32 $

Solving using above equations,
$Var(°C) = \frac{625}{81}$ and $Mean(°C) = \frac{2160}{81}$

Which gives me the required absolute difference as $\frac{1535}{81}$ which is incorrect.

Comment: What is the correct answer? Is it given?

Comment: Your $\frac{1535}{81} \not = 80 - \frac{2160}{81}$ (which in any case has several shared factors of $3$ in the numerator and denominator)

Comment: In any case $80\,^\circ F - \frac{2160}{81} \,^\circ C$ is a meaningless calculation physically, as bad as $1000$ metres $- 1$ kilometre $=999$ somethings, when clearly they are the same temperature or length so a difference of $0$.

Comment: @Souparna Unfortunately, I can only verify the correct answer once I have it. All I know is that my answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Henry I dont quite understand what you mean by 80 - 2160/81. In the problem I have to find the absolute difference of mean and variance, where both are in °C and NOT mean(°F) - Var(°C). Please read the question carefully.

Comment: What do you think "the absolute difference in mean" is asking for?

Comment: I thought it reads it as  "absolute difference in mean between Fahrenheit and Celsius"  and similarly for variance (in square degrees?).  But you seem be reading it as "absolute value of the difference between mean (measured in Celsius) and variance (measured in Celsius squared)".  Perhaps this is your difficulty